# s3 presigned url multipart formdata upload err:signature does not match

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data, pre-signed-url

I am getting a presigned url from aws and using it to request(PUT) a zip file. I get signature does not match.

when getting presigned url:

```
const params = {
            Bucket: myBucket,
            Key: myKey,
            Expires: 60*60,
            ACL: '**-**-**',
            ContentType: 'application/x-zip-compressed'};
```

when requesting:

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('filename', file.name);

fetch(url, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-zip-compressed',
                },
                body: formData
        })
```

Comment: The content type here is not "application/x-zip-compressed" but "multipart/form-data".

Answer (score -1):

Whatever `ACL` value you're using in the signature needs to also be sent in the request headers, as `'x-amz-acl': '**-**-**'`.

Note also that an S3 `PUT` does not expect `FormData` -- it expects the `body` to contain *only* the raw bytes of the object. This isn't the cause of the error, but once you correct the signature error, you'll need to change this, too, in order to get a valid, usable upload.